# How can I calculate DC motor continuous current?

Tags: power, motor, dc-motor, current-measurement, voltage-measurement

I have some information for a brushed DC motor:

```
Nominal voltage: 24 V
Omic measure: 16 ohms
Power: 400 W
Maximum output power: 550 W

Rev: 150 RPM (no load)
Test voltage: 26.0 V (no load)
Current: 2.5 A (no load)
```

Now, I'm trying to find the right motor driver and I have to calculate continuous current of motor, but I'm not sure how to do it. Here's my attempt:

$$P_{max} = I_{max} \cdot V_{max}$$

$$550W = I_{max} \cdot 24V$$

$$I_{max} = 22.9 A$$

Is my calculations correct? If not, how can I calculate the current properly?

Comment: Ohmic measure? If it is 16 ohms of rotor resistance then at 23A current the power generated in heat is going to be 8.4 kW. Doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @Andyaka it doesn't sound right to me, too. It is in motor's catalogue, but there isn't any measurement about current, continuous current etc. so, I don't know what I should do.

Comment: Find a motor with a believable data sheet.

Comment: There isn't any data sheet. I typed all measurement and I will wait until good idea.

Comment: As an almost perfect golden rule I never buy components that don't have a data sheet and this rule certainly extends to motors.

Comment: It could be believable, its just the wrong question has been asked with a more than likely innapropriate motor... That MAXIMUM power is going to be for a very short period of time. The OP question is calculate the continuous current, all that has been shown is peak current. For continuous rating thermal information is needed. A motor I am working with right now has a continuous rating of 200rpm:10A (temp settles at +50) BUT can goto 7000rpm & take 60A... the windings reach 180C in just over 1min...

Comment: 16 ohms can't possibly be correct : 0.16 ohms maybe. At 24V that would be a stall current of 1.5A, less than the no-load current. At 0.16 ohms, the numbers look more plausible : 24V 400W is 16.7A, and the stall current would be 150A. In the absence of soft start circuitry, that's what you'll see starting it. Check with the manufacturer for a missing decimal point. Otherwise, as Andy says, no data, no sale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuous rated current is the current the motor can continuously run at for a given voltage such that the temperature of the motor windings doesn't exceed the rated temperature of the insulation class of that motor.

Here is how you would test for the continuous rated current.

1. Determine the insulation class and the allowable temperature rise for that class.
2. Run the motor at the specified voltage on a dynamometer.
3. While measuring ambient temperature and winding temperature, gradually increase the torque until it reaches a steady-state temperature rise (winding temp - ambient temp) as determined in 1).
4. The current at this steady-state point is the continuous rated current.

There is no good way to calculate this unless you are prepared to model the motor both electromagnetically and thermally.

For a well designed DC motor, a general rule of thumb is that the continuous rated point will be slightly larger than the maximum efficiency of the motor.  Generally this occurs when the speed drops to about 80-90% of the no-load speed.  But that is just a rule of thumb.

Also, given that your no-load speed is 150 RPM, I'm assuming this is a gearmotor.  In this case, it could be the gearbox, not the motor, that is limiting the performance of the gearmotor.

Regarding your calculations ... 550 W is listed as the maximum output power.  This is usually much bigger than the continuous rated power of the motor (which for this motor appears to be 400 W).  Also, you can't say \$P_{max} = I_{max}*V_{max}\$ because \$P_{max}\$ is an output and \$I_{max}\$ and \$V_{max}\$ are inputs.  Your real equation would need to be \$P_{cont} = I_{cont}*V*\eta_{cont}\$, where \$\eta_{cont}\$ is the efficiency at the continuous rated point.  Plug in what you know:

\$400 W = I_{cont}*24 V*\eta_{cont} =>  I_{cont} = \frac{400 W}{24 V*\eta_{cont}}\$

For this size motor, you could estimate the efficiency to be ~80%.  That gives you \$I_{cont} = 20.8 A\$.

Note that the efficiency at maximum power will be closer to 50%, so the current at maximum power will be approximately \$\frac{550 W}{24 V*0.5} = 45.8 A\$.

But these are just estimates.  If you are building a motor driver for this motor, you will want to get the actual data from the motor manufacturer.  As others have suggested, any good manufacturer will already have this data, so if they can't give it to you easily with just a phone call or email to them, then I would suggest finding a new motor.

Answer (score 1):

Motor current is dependant on torque and voltage on speed (loosly), They don't tell you current because they don't know how much torque you will need.

Your calculation is roughly correct and if you get a driver that can source/sink 22.9A + a safety factor (10-20% for hobbiest use IMO) you will be safe. If you are a building one of these for your own use and you know not to over torque the motor then you could get a way with less.

For production you should probably get one that supports far more current (50A is the lowest I would use for this motor).

Comment: Thanks for your suggest. I thought so. By the way, maximum torque is 4.9 Nm (=50kgcm).